# How to convert Python code to executable file

Tags: python, exe, executable, pyc

I want to convert Python code to executable file which can run on any machine without Python to be installed.
pygui.py is Python file name

```
pyinstaller.exe pygui.py
```

I have try the above code but instead of executable file i got .pyc file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

The .pyc file *is* your executable file. It's not a .exe file, but it is compiled code. It will run. See [the pyinstaller manual](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) for more information about Compiled Python code.

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller should create a `dist` folder where your executable file is and all other files that need to be included in your distribution. Check out [the docs here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).

It could be that PyInstaller failed somehow. You'll have to read all of the lines in the output to get an idea of what went wrong.